# Can't add ModelBinder attribute to a property of input model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, modelbinders

I want to specify the model binder to use for a property of my input model.

```
public class SendEmailInput
{
    [Required, EmailAddress]
    public string From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string To { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required, ModelBinder(typeof(RadEditorModelBinder))]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

However the ModelBinderAttribute cannot be applied to properties. This seems stupid since I can apply it to method parameters. What should I do to work around this limitation?

Comment: damn it! I went and reorganized things expecting to be able to do this (I have a model that is sometimes bound with a complex modelbinder and sometimes with JSON)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to implement your own `PropertyBinder` like here: [MVC Property Binder](http://aboutcode.net/2011/03/12/mvc-property-binder.html)

Answer (score 0):

In wanting to specify which model binder to use, is your intention to be able to mix and re-use exising logic of the model binders?  If so, you can probably combine your logic in the custom binder itself (i'm guessing your "RadEditorModelBinder").  This way, you use 1 model binder, but the model binder itself uses different techniques based on the incoming properties.

What do you think, would that be a good alternative for you?  If so, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970335/asp-net-mvc-mixing-custom-and-default-model-binding) for further discussion.