# how to bind custom html helper extension method with model in mvc razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have made an extension method for date of birth. this extension method have three drop down list(one for day, one for month and last one for year). As this control can be used on different views, so what is the best way to bind it with different model?? I have single DOB property in the model.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest implementing a custom model binder and binding attributes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186969/custom-model-binder-for-a-property).