# Editor Template casting List to String and back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I've got an editor template for a List of objects.
This powers a JQuery token input. As such, the editor template creates a Javascript array to be loaded by a JQuery plugin.

When I come to submit that form again, the POST data appears as a comma separated string. So doesn't bind and throws an unable to cast exception.

What is the best practice for such a scenario to get the data back into my controller and have a valid ViewModel?

Editor Template

```
@model List<SEISMatch.DAL.Entities.Region>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var existingRegions = [
            @if(Model!=null){
                foreach(var region in Model){
                    if(region!=null){
                        @:{ id: @region.Id, name: "@region.Title" },
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="regionselector" name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")">
```

There is a http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ that converts that "regionselector" input into a AJAX powered token suggestion input. The value of that input ends up as a CSV string of Region IDs.

All this works correctly.

When the form is submitted, it attempts to convert the String from the input. Into a list and fails. With an unable to convert string into "Region" error.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Do you need to do any validation on each of those items in the list? If not, why don't you just make things simpler? Just, get the data as a string, and change it into a list in your POST action.

Comment: I've got validation on a number of the other properties in the ViewModel. So I'm relying on ViewModel.IsValid to check those.

Answer (score 0):

Wound up creating my own model binder but on the property level.
Following this SO answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683210/1321662