# Custom parse value for ViewModel property (Custom Bind)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bind

I have the following struct:

```
public struct DataRange
{
    public DateTime BeginDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
}
```

This struct is used on many actions of my asp.net mvc 5 app.

I am using a custom input ([daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)) and i want to bind the custom string value of the input to my custom datatype just one time and use it along my app.

E.g:

```
public class FindSalesByDateViewModel
{
    public DateRange Interval {get; set;}
}

public class SalesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(FindSalesByDateViewModel model)
    {
        //Access the model.Interval without parse the string value always.
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner on mvc development. 
I found the following solutions that are not very attractive, is there any other way to accomplish this?

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186969/custom-model-binder-for-a-property)

[Solution 2](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/customizing_property_binding_through_attributes)

**EDIT**

The custom input value that comes from view is: **"08/10/2016 - 15/10/2016"**

Answer (score 1):

You can register your custom model binder in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime)] = new YourCustomModelBinder();
```

Comment: Hi! Tks for reply, can you post a sample code/documentation link please?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Take a look at this: [Globalization: Model binding DateTimes with ASP.Net MVC](http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/globalization-model-binding-datetimes-with-asp-net-mvc) or this one: [Custom Date Formats and the MVC Model Binder](https://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/01/10/custom-date-formats-and-the-mvc-model-binder/) or this one: [Splitting DateTime - Unit Testing ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binders](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx)

Comment: On my scenario, the value cames as string, how can i register in this case?

Comment: All values come as string. But the type which you want to bind to it, is the type which you should use in `ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime)] `.

Comment: Also you can post two values `BeginDate` and `EndDate` with suitable prefix. For example if the Action is `SomeAction(DataRange model)` no prefix is needed. If you have a Model like `public class MyModel { public DataRange Range {get;set;}}` then the action should be `SomeAction(MyModel model)` and the posted values should be `model.BeginDate` and `model.EndDate`. Putting the prefix is the job of `Html.Range` or `Html.RangeFor` helper method which you created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125248/discussion-between-vinicius-goncalves-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Chat doesn't have notifications. Leave a comment instead and use chat when we both are online :)