# Create Property Model Binder in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, custom-model-binder

I have created ModelBinder for a complex class. I would like to reuse this ModelBinder on a property.
So is it possible to use ModelBinder on a property in Web API. I'm searching for an sample implementation which provides property binder like in an MVC.
Below is the reference link which i came across but those implementation is for MVC.
Any help appreciated.

[Reference Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186969/custom-model-binder-for-a-property)

[Reference Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970335/asp-net-mvc-mixing-custom-and-default-model-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same goal, however didn't find the appropriate solution to parse the exact property using binder, and not the whole model. However, there is a solution which more or less suites me - it acts pretty in same way, but requires to mark the model with attribute. I know I'm a bit late, but maybe will help someone with the same issue.

The solution is to use the custom `TypeConverter` for the required type. First of all, decide how you would like to parse your model. In my example, I need to parse search condition somehow, so my complex model is:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(OrderModelUriConverter))] // my custom type converter, which is described below
public class OrderParameter
{
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    public int OrderDirection { get; set; }
}

public class ArticlesSearchModel
{
    public OrderParameter Order { get; set; }
    // whatever else
}
```

Then decide how would you like to parse the input. In my case I simply split the values by comma.

```
public class OrderParameterUriParser
{
    public bool TryParse(string input, out OrderParameter result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var parts = input.Split(',');
        result = new OrderParameter();
        result.OrderBy = parts[0];
        int orderDirection;
        if (parts.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(parts[1], out orderDirection))
        {
            result.OrderDirection = orderDirection;
        }
        else
        {
            result.OrderDirection = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then create a converter which will take the part of query and convert it to your model using the above rules.

```
public class OrderModelUriConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private static readonly Type StringType = typeof (string);

    public OrderModelUriConverter()
    {
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == StringType)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if (str != null)
        {
            var parser = new OrderParameterParser()
            OrderParameter orderParameter;
            if (parser.TryParse(str, out orderParameter))
            {
                return orderParameter;
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

The usage of the converter is specified in the first sample. Since you are parsing URI, don't forget to add also `[FromUri]` attribute to your parameter in controller's method.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Search([FromUri] ArticlesSearchModel searchModel) // the type converter will be applied only to the property of the types marked with our attribute
{
    // do search
}
```

Also, you can take a look at [this excellent article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), which contains similar example and also several other ways of parsing parameters.