# Mixing Custom and Default Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to run some code to **further databind** some model after the default model binding is done. I don't want to completely replace the existing model binding.

This question explains how this is done in pre-CORE ASP.NET:
[ASP.NET MVC - Mixing Custom and Default Model Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970335/asp-net-mvc-mixing-custom-and-default-model-binding)

However that approach doesn't seem to work in ASP.NET Core because there is no **DefaultModelBinder** class any more.

What alternative can be used in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `ComplexTypeModelBinder` to do the actual work, then inject your own logic after it is done.

For example (assuming your custom type is `MyCustomType`):

```
public class MyCustomType
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> _propertyBinders;

    public MyCustomTypeModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders)
    {
        this._propertyBinders = propertyBinders;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var complexTypeModelBinder = new ComplexTypeModelBinder(this._propertyBinders);

        // call complexTypeModelBinder
        await complexTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);

        var modelBound = bindingContext.Model as MyCustomType;

        // do your own magic here
        modelBound.Foo = "custominjected";
    }
}

public class MyCustomTypeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(MyCustomType))
        {
            var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();

            for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
            }

            return new MyCustomTypeModelBinder(propertyBinders);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then register it:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyCustomTypeModelBinderProvider());
});
```