# .NET core custom and default binding combined

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, custom-model-binder, defaultmodelbinder

I'm creating a custom model binder for a view model, implementing `IModelBinder`

I have a lot of properties in my view model, the majority of which do not need any custom binding. Rather than explicitly set all of the property values on my model individually from the `ModelBindingContext`, I would to be able to get the framework to bind the model for me, then I would carry out any custom binding:

```
public class ApplicationViewModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // get .net core to bind values on model

        // Cary out any customization of the models properties

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);
        return Task.CompletedTask; 
    }
}
```

Basically I want to carry out the default model binding, then apply custom binding, similar to the approach taken in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970335/asp-net-mvc-mixing-custom-and-default-model-binding) but for .NET Core, not framework.

I assumed applying the default binding would be straight forward, but haven't been able to find out how to do so. I believe the solution would involve `ComplexTypeModelBinder` and `ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider` classes, but can't seem to find out how to go about it.

I know I could just make any changes when the POST request hits my controller method, but this seem the wrong place and wrong time to do so.

Answer (score 8):

For custom `ComplexTypeModelBinder`, you could inherit from `ComplexTypeModelBinder`.

1. Model

```cs
    public class BinderModel
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string BinderValue { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Controller Action

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromForm]BinderModel value)
    {

    }
```

3. CustomBinder

```cs
    public class CustomBinder : ComplexTypeModelBinder
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> _propertyBinders;
        public CustomBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders)
        : base(propertyBinders)
        {
            _propertyBinders = propertyBinders;
        }
        protected override Task BindProperty(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.FieldName == "BinderValue")
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success("BinderValueTest");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.BindProperty(bindingContext);
            }
        }
        protected override void SetProperty(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string modelName, ModelMetadata propertyMetadata, ModelBindingResult result)
        {
            base.SetProperty(bindingContext, modelName, propertyMetadata, result);
        }
    }
```

4. CustomBinderProvider

```cs
    public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && !context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
            {
                var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
                for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
                {
                    var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                    propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
                }

                //var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                //return new ComplexTypeModelBinder(propertyBinders, loggerFactory);
                return new CustomBinder(propertyBinders);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

5. Inject provider

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
        });
    }
```

Comment: ComplexTypeModelBinder does not have a single-parameter constructor.  IModelBinder worked for me instead.

Answer (score 3):

[ComplexTypeModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.complextypemodelbinder) has unfortunately been deprecated in .Net 5.0, and it's counterpart, [ComplexObjectModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.complexobjectmodelbinder), is sealed, so you can't extend from it.

But, you can work around that. [ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.complexobjectmodelbinderprovider) is public, and you can use that to create a `ComplexObjectModelBinder`. Thus, if you make your own custom [IModelBinderProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinderprovider), you can have the constructor accept a `ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider` argument, and make use of that to make a `ComplexObjectModelBinder`. Then, you can pass that to your custom [IModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinder), where it'll happily do its custom work before falling back to the `ComplexObjectModelBinder` you supplied.

Here's an example. First, your `IModelBinder`. This example shows that you can use DI if you want to. (In this example, say we needed a DbContext.)

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelBinder _defaultBinder;
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public MyCustomModelBinder(IModelBinder defaultBinder, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _defaultBinder = defaultBinder;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public override Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // -do custom work here-

        return _defaultBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

However, in order to use DI on your custom model binder, you'll need a helper class. The problem is, when `IModelBinderProvider` is called, it won't have access to all the services in a typical request, like your DbContext for example. But this class will help:

```
internal class DIModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelBinder _rootBinder;
    private readonly ObjectFactory _factory;

    public DIModelBinder(Type binderType, IModelBinder rootBinder)
    {
        if (!typeof(IModelBinder).IsAssignableFrom(binderType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Your binderType must derive from IModelBinder.");
        }
        
        _factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(binderType, new[] { typeof(IModelBinder) });
        _rootBinder = rootBinder;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var requestServices = bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var binder = (IModelBinder)_factory(requestServices, new[] { _rootBinder });
        return binder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Now you're ready to write the custom `IModelBinderProvider`:

```
public class MyCustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private readonly IModelBinderProvider _rootProvider;
    public MyCustomModelBinderProvider(IModelBinderProvider rootProvider)
    {
        _rootProvider = rootProvider;
    }
    
    public IModelBinder? GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(MyModel))
        {
            var rootBinder = _rootProvider.GetBinder(context)
                ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Root {_rootProvider.GetType()} did not provide an IModelBinder for MyModel.");

            return new DIModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder), rootBinder);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your startup file where you configure services, you can grab the `ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider` instance, use that to create a new instance of your `MyCustomModelBinderProvider`, and insert that into the `ModelBinderProviders`.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var fallbackProvider = options.ModelBinderProviders
        .First(p => p is ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider);
    var myProvider = new MyCustomModelBinderProvider(fallbackProvider);
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, myProvider);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've found that running the default binder _after_ my custom binding work will override that. I can run the default binder before but it means it will explode if it tries to parse a required field that it cant handle because of the custom binding I need to do on it. Is there some way to prevent the default binder overriding the values I set?